# Trying to run selenium test using a azure pipeline. ADO is hosted in public tenant.AUT does not allow access from public agents and blocks the id

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-network

Elaborating the issue:

Trying to run selenium test using a azure pipeline VS test task.
ADO is hosted in public tenant(Microsoft Tenant). AUT is very secure and does not allow access from public agents and blocks the id which I am using to run the selenium test every time I try to login into the application.

Hence I cannot run my tests on a pipeline

Is there any way that I will be able to access the AUT and run my tests on a pipeline.

Comment: Set up a private agent within the secured environment.

Comment: Can you please Elaborate on how can we achieve this or point me to some documentation available for this

Comment: Refer to the documentation on private agents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what AUT is, but here are two ideas you can refer to:

1. If you use Microsoft-hosted agent, you need to add the ip of the agent to your
   environment's whitelist. (Not recommended)

- You can add all the possible IP ranges of the MS-hosted agents in your Azure geography according to [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). Since the IPs of the MS-hosted agent are updated every week, you need to check and update the whitelist weekly.
- If you just want to add the current agent's ip to the whitelist, you can use the following PowerShell script. But because the MS-agent assigned to the pipeline is different each time, you have to update the whitelist every time you run the pipeline. So this method is more suitable if you can use a script to automatically update the whitelist.

  $ip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
  Write-Host "The IP address of current agent machine is $ip"

2. The first method is not very convenient. As suggested by Prashant Thakuri, you can set up a self-hosted agent in your environment, or add the ip of the self-hosted agent to your environment's whitelist. To set up a self-hosted agent, you can refer to [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).